# Play Framework/Scala: Editing data in a form object

Tags: scala, playframework

How do I edit elements in the data map of a Form?
Assume you bind the received data by...

```
val form = User.userEditForm.bindFromRequest
```

...then you test if everything is alright using fold....

```
form.fold (formWithErrors => {
  BadRequest(views.html.userEditForm(formWithErrors))
},
new_user => {
  .....
}
```

. In the first branch "formWithErrors" you redisplay the form and pass the formWithErrors as paramater.

Let's assume we have a field password and we want to empty this field before we redisplay the form for correction.
Or we want to clean up all field in the form.data by removing all whitespaces at the beginning/end of each field.
Thus simple question how can I update any field in the form.data hashmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form` is a case class, so you can use the `copy` method to copy new data into it:

```
val form = Form {
    mapping(
        "email" -> email,
        "password" -> nonEmptyText,
        "something" -> number
    )
}

form.bindFromRequest.fold (
    formWithErrors => {
        BadRequest(views.html.userEditForm(
            formWithErrors.copy(data = formWithErrors.data + ("password" -> ""))
        ))
    },
    user => ...
)
```